# $\sigma$-algebra of coin tosses until first head

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that a coin is tossed until a heads is obtained. For this situation, what would be the tripe $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$?

For the sample space, I suppose it would be
$$\Omega := \{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, ...\}$$

Now, to properly define a probability measure such that for $n$ tosses we have $P( TT...TH)= 1/2^n$. I suppose we need to define an algebra where this probability measure works, and then expand using Caratheodóry. Am I correct in assuming this? If so, what would be the algebra to which I'd expand in order to use Caratheodory? Or does the $\sigma$-algebra of the set of all combinations (i.e. $2^\Omega$) works as my $\mathcal F$?

Comment: I would take $\Omega$ as the set of infinite sequences of points in {0,1} such that 1 occupies the entry which corresponds to the appearence of the first head and all other entries would be zero. I can't explain why, but I feel this would help make things preciser later on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probability measure should be a function from your $\sigma$-algebra to $[0,1]$. For instance, you could take $\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$.

If you can just define the probability measure and $\sigma$-algebra right off the bat, I wouldn't bother thinking about caratheodory and premeasure nonsense. Here, your life is a bit easier because $\Omega$ is countable.

Comment: How does the fact that is countable helps?

Comment: It means you won't have to worry about sets which are not measurable in your power set, like you have in the case of the Lebesgue measure (see e.g. the Vitali set)

Comment: I see. But I mean, how does one prove this assertion? That indeed the use of the power set is non-problematic,

Comment: For the general case I am not sure off the top of my head. For this case, any element of $A \in 2^\Omega$ is an at most countable collection of strings of the form $TTT\cdots TTH$. Each of the strings in your subset $A$ represents a disjoint event and your measure is defined on each one.

Answer (score 0):

Another natural way I might suggest is to embed your situation inside the canonical coin toss space $\Omega = \{ H, T \}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Here the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is the one generated by the collection of cylinder sets of the sort $\mathcal{C}_x =\{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega_1 = x_1, \dots, \omega_n = x_n \}$ for each $n \geq 1$, where $x = (x_i)_{i = 1}^n$ with each $x_i \in \{ H, T \}$.

Then the classic argument is to build a probability measure on this space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ using Carathéodory's extension theorem with $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{C}_x) = 1/2^n$ for the same example given above. (Technically we have a "semi-algebra" here that can readily be extended to an algebra; but there is a version of Carathéodory's that works here too. I found a nice explanation in Section 6.5 of [these notes](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2400/v13/mathanalch6.pdf) on building the coin-tossing measure).

This way, you can still capture everything you need to know about the tosses until the first head (e.g. by the random variable $T$). For example, the event $\{ T = k \}$ corresponds exactly to the cylinder set $\{ \omega \in \Omega: \omega_1 = \dots = \omega_{k-1} = T, \, \omega_k = H \}$, which has probability $1/2^k$.